# Pandas groupby strip timezone in index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timezone

I have run into a problem where my timezone information get stripped off when I filter a dataframe for unique index values (this is done using both groupby() and first()).  e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz

utc = pytz.utc

index = pd.date_range('20140101','20140102',freq='6H',tz=utc)
data  = pd.np.random.randint(0,10,(5,3))
namen = list('abc')

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=index,columns=namen)
```

Timezone info is now stored in the index:

```
>>>df.index[0]

    Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

When I keep only unique values I lose timestamp info.

```
df = df.groupby(df.index).first()

>>> df.index[0]
    Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

Sure, I could use .drop_duplicates() to do the same thing (.drop_duplicates() seems to retain the timezone info), but this has two problems for my current work:

1. drop_duplicates does not operate on the index, which is important (see #2)
2. Due to the nature of my dataset it is very likely that I will have identical rows within the dataframe, so using drop_duplicates will remove these otherwise-good rows.

I could use drop_duplicates by making a new column within the dataframe to hold the index values.  e.g.

```
df['dates'] = df.index
df = df.drop_duplicates(cols=['dates'])
df.pop('dates')
```

While this works, it seems sloppy.  Is there an alternative here that I do not see?

Comment: I'm not seeing this. What version of pandas, pytz, and numpy are you using?

Comment: Pandas 0.12.0, pytz 2013b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas 0.15.1, I don't see the same thing you do:

```
In [90]: so_df
Out[90]: 
                           a  b  c
2014-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  3  6  2
2014-01-01 06:00:00+00:00  9  3  5
2014-01-01 12:00:00+00:00  2  9  4
2014-01-01 18:00:00+00:00  3  6  3
2014-01-02 00:00:00+00:00  4  1  4

In [93]: so_df.index[3]
Out[93]: Timestamp('2014-01-01 18:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='6H')

In [94]: so_df2 = so_df.groupby(so_df.index).first()

In [95]: so_df2
Out[95]: 
                           a  b  c
2014-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  3  6  2
2014-01-01 06:00:00+00:00  9  3  5
2014-01-01 12:00:00+00:00  2  9  4
2014-01-01 18:00:00+00:00  3  6  3
2014-01-02 00:00:00+00:00  4  1  4

In [96]: so_df2.index[3]
Out[96]: Timestamp('2014-01-01 18:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='6H')
```

Version 0.15.0 improved [several things](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/whatsnew.html#timezone-handling-improvements) relating to timezones, including

> - a timeseries/index localized to UTC when inserted into a Series/DataFrame will preserve the UTC timezone (rather than being a naive `datetime64[ns]`) as `object` dtype ([GH8411](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8411))

Hopefully upgrading will solve your issue. Please note that as of 0.15.0,

> pandas >= 0.15.0 will no longer support compatibility with NumPy versions < 1.7.0. If you want to use the latest versions of pandas, please upgrade to NumPy >= 1.7.0 ([GH7711](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7711))

Since you're upgrading, now might be a good time to take a look at the installed versions of pandas' [dependencies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/install.html#dependencies) and upgrade any of those that might be getting a little stale.

Good luck!

Comment: Updated to 15 and I now see same results as you.  This makes me wonder though, what is this "offset" that I now see in my Timestamp?  I have not found a good explanation in a quick web search.  I understand it is representing the frequency of my time series, but what is the use?

Comment: @tnknepp I'm not sure what role it plays, other than storing data about the time series itself.